# Passing a delegate as an Attribute

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705386/is-it-possible-to-have-a-delegate-as-attribute-parameter) method to pass a delegate as a parameter.

```
public delegate Guid SpaceIdGetter();
public class SpaceIdAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public SpaceIdGetter spaceGetter { get; set; }

        public SpaceIdAttribute(Type delegateType, string delegateName)
        {
            spaceGetter = (SpaceIdGetter)Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, delegateType.GetMethod(delegateName));
        }
    }

    public static class ContextInfo
    {
        public static SpaceIdGetter GetSpaceId()
        {
            return new SpaceIdGetter( () =>
                    {
                        return Guid.Empty;
                    }
                );
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error when I try to create the delegate with reflection

```
spaceGetter = (SpaceIdGetter)Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, delegateType.GetMethod(delegateName));
```

> Type must derive from Delegate.

Edit: here's how I'm using it

```
[SpaceId(typeof(ContextInfo), "GetSpaceId")]
public virtual string Body { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you please show the complete calling code?

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that. Edited the post.

Comment: In `c# 6.0` you can use `nameof(GetSpaceId)` instead of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContextInfo` is actually a factory already creating the delegate type - so no need to create delegate via reflection - you just have to call the factory via reflection:

```
public SpaceIdAttribute(Type delegateType, string delegateName)
{
  var factoryMethod = delegateType.GetMethod(delegateName);
  spaceGetter = (SpaceIdGetter)factoryMethod.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ContextInfo is not a Delegate and Delegate.CreateDelegate must take a delegate. Try: 
    `spaceGetter = (SpaceIdGetter)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<Guid>), delegateType.GetMethod(delegateName));`

Comment: Getting this now: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.