# C# ASP.NET MVC Foolproof RequiredIf - how to set ErrorMessage to be the value of other (string) property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, customvalidator, foolproof-validation

That's what I'm looking for:

```
[RequiredIf("IsNewClient", true, ErrorMessage =*The value of other (string) property*)]
```

That's would be even better:

```
[RequiredIf("IsNewClient", true, ErrorMessage =*Calling a function and get the value*)]
```

Comment: If you take a look at the code (https://github.com/leniel/foolproof/tree/master/Foolproof) you'll see that Foolproof doesn't provide this functionality. So you'd have to subclass `RequiredIfAttribute` and add it yourself if you want it. I think you'll have trouble implementating the behavior you want though, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705386/is-it-possible-to-have-a-delegate-as-attribute-parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use a similar approach like that:

```
[RequiredIf("GoAbroad == true")]
public string PassportNumber { get; set; }
```

For more information have a look at [ExpressiveAnnotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations). Hope this helps...